# Can you build an app in Corona SDK using C#?

Tags: c#, android, ios, lua, coronasdk

I want to take advantage of Corona's powerful SDK, but I have several large private C# libraries that I need to use as well. I have read about LuaInterface allowing one to run Lua code from a C# application, but I'm not sure how to build and run the app in Corona. Is this impossible to do?

Corona: https://coronalabs.com/products/corona-sdk/

Using Lua with C#: http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/using-lua-with-c-r2275

Edit: So I have discovered that Corona has several frameworks that allow a C# application to run and manage Corona based apps: 
https://docs.coronalabs.com/coronacards/wp8/communication.html
https://docs.coronalabs.com/native/wp8/html/html/R_Project_CoronaLabs_Corona_WindowsPhone.htm

These functions seem to only be available in the Enterprise version, which requires 80$/developer/month.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simply no. Corona SDK is based on lua and you can only use lua for coding your app / game.

However if you want to enable your Corona SDK to be able to import any native library you may switch to the paid version I.e Corona Enterprise.

Visit for more info

[Corona Labs](http://coronalabs.com)

Answer (score 0):

Corona Enterprise allows you to use Corona SDK's API's with native libraries.

See: https://coronalabs.com/products/enterprise/